# Populating a drop-down select list

Tags: php, mysql, xml, drop-down-menu

I want to populate some HTML select lists using PHP. E.g. If I were to populate a drop down with a list of values, which would be quicker and easier to maintain? I'm talking really about lists that rarely if ever change such as countries, US states, colors, towns, cities etc.

- Store the values as an array in a separate php file and include it. Then loop through and output each value.
- Store the values in an XML file, load file with simpleXML, loop through each value and output.
- Store in a MySQL db, connect to db, retrieve countries, loop through and output them. (When I backup my db I'll be constantly backing up tables which never change)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Option 1 here. Option 2, using XML will require more resource and execution time. Option 3 is OK. But as you see there will be no change in the data, it would be better to store the values as an array. But be sure you are not using this data in your database for any relationship. If there is one, Option 3 would be easier and convenient.

But the scenario is as you described, use Option 1.